# Implementacion de Motor de Reglas en .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy queriendo implementar un motor de reglas en la empresa. Lo que vi en el mercado son herramientas de pago y gratis.

La que me llamó mucho la atención es una llamada NXBre que parace bastante desarrollada y es gratuita. EL problema con esta es que no hay documentación por ningún lado, y cualquier cosa que quise hacer, me es imposible dado que no hay documentación que dé soporte.

La pregunta es que recomiendan para agregar un motor de reglas en .net? Si es NXBre, ¿dónde puedo tener una buena implementación (Aplicación Empresarial) que permita hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: Es NXBre no un clase de queso desde Francia o algo asi? De verded, nunca he oido de este. Ha hice un busque en stackoverflow por preguntas acerca de NXBre?

Comment: Hola @mpanichella, te comento que las preguntas abiertas y subjetivas como la tuya son, generalmente, cerradas ya que cualquier respuesta que te den [es igualmente válida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Te recomiendo que reescribas tu pregunta para exponer un verdadero problema, específico y reproducible,

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que un motor de reglas sería un motor de workflow.

La librería que mencionas hay poca info [NxBRE wiki](https://github.com/ddossot/NxBRE/wiki)

No evaluaste [Window Workflow Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  podría ser una alternativa válida que se encuentra integrada dentro de .net, recuerda que puedes o no usar los diagramas visuales para crear las reglas, podrías crear actividades y ejecutarlas desde código.

O quizás sea útil [WorkflowEngine.NET](https://workflowengine.codeplex.com/)